# how to add 1 year to date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

im newbie in javascript. all i want to do is add 1 year to current date that i selected from date picker. but the solution i build return me an error which is uncaught execption.

i also need it auto calculate the 1 year period by selecting the calendar. in my case, i noob-ly put onMouseOver to do the auto calculation...

here is my code

```
<b>Start Date:</b><br>
        <div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
        <input  size="16" type="text" name="date_start" id="date_start" onMouseOver="endDate('date_start')">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>

        <script>
            function endDate(elemid) {

            //take value 
            var ind = document.getElementById(elemid).value;
            //calculate the year 
            var parseDate = Date.parse(ind);
            //put into age textbox
            console.log(parseDate);
            document.getElementById("end_date").value = result; 
            } 
        </script>

<b>End Date:</b><br>
        <input type="text" class="span4" name="end_date" id="end_date">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Datepicker - Add Years](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067765/jquery-datepicker-add-years)

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686243/jquery-javascript-add-years-to-date-variable